# Xcode 7 removing project reference

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, delete-file

I'd really like to know how to permanently remove those annoying Xcode project references, I deleted my projects where they were located at in ~/Xcode Projects and I have deleted it in the Xcode menu Window -> Projects but it is still exists in the start menu of Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed it in recently opened projects in the menu bar of Xcode (on OSX), now they don't show up anymore.